# 'docker load' command failed with error ...'

Tags: jhipster

Following [the "Create Full Microservice Stack Using Jhipster Domain Language Under 30 Minutes" article](https://medium.com/@deepu105/create-full-microservice-stack-using-jhipster-domain-language-under-30-minutes-ecc6e7fc3f77), I run into a problem after running

```
./gradlew bootWar -Pprod jibDockerBuild  (not the command mentioned in the article ./gradlew -Pprod bootWar buildDocker)
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Build to Docker daemon failed
  andardTaskAction.java:46)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 'docker load' command failed with error: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/images/load?quiet=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.load(DockerClient.java:102)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LoadDockerStep.afterPushBaseImageLayerFuturesFuture(LoadDockerStep.java:95)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$CallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:181)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.$closeResource(DockerClient.java:104)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.load(DockerClient.java:104)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LoadDockerStep.afterPushBaseImageLayerFuturesFuture(LoadDockerStep.java:95)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$CallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:181)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.hash.CountingDigestOutputStream.write(CountingDigestOutputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.CountingOutputStream.write(CountingOutputStream.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream$BufferAtATimeOutputChannel.write(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:241)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.writeBlock(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.maybeFlush(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:86)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.write(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.write(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:452)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.hash.CountingDigestOutputStream.write(CountingDigestOutputStream.java:83)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:110)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.blob.BlobDescriptor.fromPipe(BlobDescriptor.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.blob.FileBlob.writeTo(FileBlob.java:38)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.tar.TarStreamBuilder.writeEntriesAsTarArchive(TarStreamBuilder.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.blob.WriterBlob.writeTo(WriterBlob.java:36)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.load(DockerClient.java:88)
    ... 3 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: This archive contains unclosed entries.
            at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.finish(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:289)
            at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.close(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:306)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.tar.TarStreamBuilder.writeEntriesAsTarArchive(TarStreamBuilder.java:54)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.blob.WriterBlob.writeTo(WriterBlob.java:36)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.load(DockerClient.java:88)
            at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LoadDockerStep.afterPushBaseImageLayerFuturesFuture(LoadDockerStep.java:95)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$CallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:181)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Do I need to set up an account on DockerHub to resolve this problem? If yes, how can I pass my account information on the command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your user is missing the permissions of the group docker , but beware this group is nearly like an root user. Try to send your command with sudo to get the permission to access the **socket on your pc** it doesnt matter if you have an docker acc as far as i can see